# Sorting listview by colums results in empty lists showing first

Tags: c#, listview, sorting, items

I want to sort my listview by columns and I used this example code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401.
It works but at the end of listview I have some blank items and when I click a column these items become first items and I need them at the end. How can I make the code to skip the blank items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have implemented the whole example you can change this part of the Compare method:

```
// Compare the two items
compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
                                      listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
```

to something like:

```
// Compare the two items
compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
                                      listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
if (listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text=="") 
        compareResult = (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending ? -1:  1);
else if (listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text=="") 
       compareResult = (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending ? 1 : -1);
```

This should override the original result of the comparison.

Watch how you check for empty items, could be null, too or whatever you did before..!

Comment: Hello, Your answer works but only ascending not descending. It goes: Blank -> Z -> Y -> X -> W -> V - > U -> etc.

Comment: I have edited the answer using the SortOrder that is being used. Of course now the blank items will always stay at the end; i hadn't expected you'd want that, but as you see, this isn't much additional code. I hope it works..